# Cannot install cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to both Linux and C++, and I am trying to install cmake, when I tried to install it using `sudo apt install cmake` it installed cmake version 3.10, but [here is stated that at least version 3.15 is required](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux):  and when I tried to install newer version using `sudo snap install cmake` as Linux terminal suggests I get an error `cannot install "cmake" Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh:dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: no such host` Maybe the error is caused by the fact that I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual machine and I do not have internet access with it. So I tried to install cmake.sh from [here](https://cmake.org/download/) and transfer it to Ubuntu via Windows/Linux shared folder but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a newer version of cmake, follow these steps:

**Remove the old version of cmake:**

```
sudo apt remove --purge cmake
hash -r
```

**Install newer version of cmake:**
1- first method: using Snap

```
sudo snap install cmake --classic
```

2- second method: install from source

```
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev
wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.16.5/cmake-3.16.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf cmake-3.16.5.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.16.5
./bootstrap
make 
sudo make install
```

**Check cmake version:**

```
cmake --version
```

If you want to download a different version, check [this website](https://cmake.org/download/)

**Credit:** [Installing the latest CMake on Ubuntu 18.04](https://graspingtech.com/upgrade-cmake/)

**N.B:** I tested the second method (install from source) and it works well.

Comment: `hash -r` is magic.  before this, cmake is broken no matter  apt or snap is used.